# pipe and tee doesn't receive output in a file..(bash)

Tags: bash, pipe, stdout, stderr

I wanted get the resout of `ps` command to a file like this. (in bash)

```
$ps -eax |& tee list1
```

and I see many lines from the ps command but the file list1 is empty.
How should I do it?

Comment: what was the intention behind using `|&`?

Comment: I usually did to catch stderr too.

Comment: the problem is I can't reproduce this locally; my `list1` is filled with the output of ps. So I thought maybe I was doing something wrong, and hence I asked for clarification.

Comment: Note that you need bash 4.0 or newer for `|&` (short for `2>&1 |`, `|&` being a csh operator initially). In older versions, I'd expect a syntax error though.

Comment: maybe we need to do a sanity check on `tee`. What does `type tee` say? And `tee --version`?

Comment: Also `ls -ld list` while we're at it.

Comment: oh and I know this is a bit silly, but what does `echo "shell: ${shell} SHELL: ${SHELL}"` say?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas (which would make it more likely the shell in question is not bash, csh or zsh; Bash 4 was, um, 2010?)

Comment: @MarcusMüller, still 3.2 was the last one licensed under GPL2 which is probably why that's the one you find on macos.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas oooh I didn't know that!

Comment: `|&` is the operator to start a co-process in ksh. `ps -eax |& tee list1` would run `ps -eax` as a coproc and then start `tee list1` in foreground with its stdin still on the terminal device (and hang there waiting for input).

Comment: @MarcusMüller it says `shell:  SHELL: /bin/bash`

Comment: Ha.. I recevied a notice about someone answering to my question and I tried `$ps -eax |& tee list1` again and it works now! I don't know what's happening..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get your desired logging in parallel to terminal output, you should change

```
$ps -eax |& tee list1
```

to

```
$ps -eax 2>&1 | tee list1
```

As suggested by the discussion, it is possible that the "|&" operator is not implemented in a universal fashion, causing discrepancies from one system to the next, or that it is reacting to unspecified environmental conditions.

Comment: Hi, I tried `$ps -eax |& tee list1` again and it works today! I don't know why.